# Pass local variable to create.js.erb for an iteration in an iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Post` and a `Comment` model, while a post can have multiple comments and a comment belongs to a post (and a user).

I am iterating through all Posts by doing `@posts.each do |d|`, which is not a big deal. Also i am iterating through all the comments of a Post by `d.comments.each do |comment|`. No big deal too.

Ive setted up a `create.js.erb` to make my app a bit more dynamic and to instantly display the comment you created under a post. While my form is working fine, i have troubles setting up the `create.js.erb` which is giving me a `NameError - undefined local variable or method 'comment' for #<Class:> Did you mean?  @comment:` when submitting the forms content. After reloading the page the comment is added up, but i would like to have an instant update like a single page app would behave. i have never worked with ajax before.

I would be able to solve the whole situation if i would just display the comments on a separate `posts#show` view but since i am iterating through every post on the index page and want to display every comment of every post and also update the comments async i just cant figure out how to do that.

How do I create the desired behavior?

Sorry if my question is asked kinda wonky.

`comments_controller.rb`

```
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = @user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.js {}
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Comment added' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to root_path }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

`posts/index.html.erb`

```
<% @posts.each do |d| %>
  <%= d.content %>

  <div class="comment-list">
    <%= render partial: "comments/comment", collection: d.comments %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`comments/_comment.html.erb`

```
<%# d.comments.reverse.each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.content %>
<%# end %>
```

`create.js.erb`

```
$(".comment-list").append("<%= j render partial: "comments/comment" %>");
```

Comment: post your new  comment view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".comment-list").append("<%= j render partial: "comments/comment" %>");
```

Replace above code with

```
$(".comment-list").append("<%= j render partial: "comments/comment", locals: {comment: @comment} %>");
```

Comment: I cant believe that. i did the exact same, i swear! but now its working :D thank you very much!

Comment: Your welcome, You can contact me any time @GabrielTheCoder

Comment: thats nice of you! Maybe you can help with another thing. My _comment.html.erb partial is rendering the comments in the "right" way. is there a way to turn the order around, like .reverse would do? @MayurKambariya

Comment: $(".comment-list").prepend("<%= j render partial: "comments/comment", locals: {comment: @comment} %>");

Try this for reverse order

Comment: Replace append with prepend @GabrielTheCoder

Comment: *facepalm* thank you for answering my stupid questions :D @MayurKambariya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230644/discussion-between-mayur-kambariya-and-gabrielthecoder).